# invalidate authentication token when user disabled by admin

Tags: wso2-identity-server

is it possible in wso2 identity server when user is disabled or locked by admin or any other scenario and then user session can be invalidated just in time and user's authentication token is disabled?
Once user login and have a valid session, but after this time,  admin lock the user and deactivates user account. now user will access to protect resource and will against as your token is validate. is user's token valid yet?

Answer (score 0):

Please specify the IS version that you are using. In IS 5.1 the user can't access to any resource once his account is locked. I'm not quite sure about IS 5.0 though.

Thanks